# How do I combine data from a Pandas DataFrame with a multiindex into a list

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe with a multiindex, the result of a pivot (as in the pivot pandas function description)

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'foo': ['one', 'one', 'one', 'two', 'two',
                       'two'],
               'bar': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C'],
               'baz': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
               'zoo': ['x', 'y', 'z', 'q', 'w', 't']})
df

    foo bar baz zoo
0   one A   1   x
1   one B   2   y
2   one C   3   z
3   two A   4   q
4   two B   5   w
5   two C   6   t

dp = df.pivot(index='foo', columns='bar', values=['baz', 'zoo'])
dp

          baz         zoo
bar A   B   C   A   B   C
foo                     
one 1   2   3   x   y   z
two 4   5   6   q   w   t
```

I want make it look like this:

```
bar     A       B       C
foo         
one [1,x]   [2,y]   [3,z]
two [4,q]   [5,w]   [6,t]
```

Where the data from the level 0 index are combined in a list...
Any ideas how this could be done? Tried agg(list) but that did not work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to combine columns `baz` and `zoo` first and then pivot the table:

```
df['combined'] = list(zip(df.baz, df.zoo))

df.pivot('foo', 'bar', 'combined')
#bar       A       B       C
#foo                        
#one  (1, x)  (2, y)  (3, z)
#two  (4, q)  (5, w)  (6, t)
```